# Gameband won't open on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, minecraft

I have had a Gameband for a while now, but I just recently switched over to Ubuntu 16.04.02 from Windows 10. Every time I try to open Gameband.exe, it gives me an error message that says "an error occurred while loading the archive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exe` files are for Windows. They won't run on Ubuntu

Comment: is there a way to open it using something else though?

Comment: Yes, you can look into using wine for it. YMMV.